# Remove quotes from named environment variables in Windows scripts

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, environment-variables, quotes

I want to store a URL prefix in an Windows environment variable. The ampersands in the query string makes this troublesome though.

For example: I have a URL prefix of `http://example.com?foo=1&bar=` and want to create a full URL by providing a value for the `bar` parameter. I then want to launch that URL using the "start" command.

Adding quotes around the value for the SET operation is easy enough:

```
set myvar="http://example.com?foo=1&bar="
```

Windows includes the quotes in the actual value though (thanks Windows!):

```
echo %myvar%
"http://example.com?foo=1&bar=true"
```

I know that I can strip quotes away from batch file arguments by using tilde:

```
echo %~1
```

However, I can't seem to do it to named variables:

```
echo %~myvar%
%~myvar%
```

What's the syntax for accomplishing this?

Comment: Rarely, a question alone helps me solve my current problem (how to strip quotes from a batch file argument). Here, it did. Thanks and +1 :-)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is not a limitation of the environment variable, but rather the command shell.

Enclose the entire assignment in quotes:

```
set "myvar=http://example.com?foo=1&bar="
```

Though if you try to echo this, it will complain as the shell will see a break in there.

You can echo it by enclosing the var name in quotes:

```
echo "%myvar%"
```

Or better, just use the set command to view the contents:

```
set myvar
```

Comment: Should this work with SET /P? I try SET /P "var=question". var is then equal to "my response with spaces"

Answer (score 39):

echo %myvar:"=%

Answer (score 11):

While there are several good answers already, another way to remove quotes is to use a simple subroutine:

```
:unquote
  set %1=%~2
  goto :EOF
```

Here's a complete usage example:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION ENABLEEXTENSIONS

set words="Two words"
call :unquote words %words%
echo %words%

set quoted="Now is the time"
call :unquote unquoted %quoted%
echo %unquoted%

set word=NoQuoteTest
call :unquote word %word%
echo %word%

goto :EOF

:unquote
  set %1=%~2
  goto :EOF
```

Comment: Glad someone else thought of this, though, thinking deeper -- what if the variable doesn't have quotes?  would be nice to have an early abort check, rather than just truncating the existing var...

Comment: %~2 removes any surrounding quotes. If there are no quotes it doesn't truncate.

Comment: What's the `rem set %1=%~2` for? It looks like a commented out duplicate of the next line. Also, if the contents of the variable are not quoted and contain a space, this seems to truncate everything after the first space. Unless I've done something wrong, that would seem to make this unsuitable for dealing with file names.

Comment: @jpmc26, that was a meaningless comment left in by mistake. I've removed it. Thanks for bringing this to my attention.

Answer (score 9):

This works

```
for %a in (%myvar%) do set myvar=%~a
```

I would also use this if I wanted to print a variable that contained and ampersand without the quotes.

```
for %a in ("fish & chips") do echo %~a
```

Answer (score 3):

To remove only beginning and ending quotes from a variable:

```
SET myvar=###%myvar%###
SET myvar=%myvar:"###=%
SET myvar=%myvar:###"=%
SET myvar=%myvar:###=%
```

This assumes you don't have a ###" or "### inside your value, and does not work if the variable is NULL.

Credit goes to http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html for this method.

Answer (score 2):

Use delayed environment variable expansion and use !var:~1,-1! to remove the quotes:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set myvar="http://example.com?foo=1&bar="
set myvarWithoutQuotes=!myvar:~1,-1!
echo !myvarWithoutQuotes!
```

Answer (score 1):

Use multiple variables to do it:

```
set myvar="http://example.com?foo=1&bar="

set bar=true

set launch=%testvar:,-1%%bar%"

start iexplore %launch%
```

Comment: Um ... `myvar` or `testvar` or what?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set "myvar=http://example.com?foo=1&bar="
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo !myvar!
```

This is because the variable contains special shell characters.

Answer (score -1):

I think this should do it:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %i in (%myvar%) do set %myvar%=%~i
```

But you do not need this,

```
set myvar="http://example.com?foo=1&bar="
start "" %myvar%
```

Will work too, you just need to supply a title to the start command.

Comment: The start command doesn't work. The ampersand in the URL terminates the line, thus dropping the last URL param. It launches the browser but it's the wrong URL.